# Is there a way to ignore flow errors?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-automation, fault-connector

I have an auto launched flow that I would like to just ignore the errors of if they occur.

I currently have several fault connectors going to a dummy assignment. However I keep receiving error emails which is what I am trying to avoid.

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for this. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_troubleshoot_error_email.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null. You will need to setup an email to receive the exception emails.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I have an email setup. I am trying to not receive the emails. Basically I want the flow to handle the exception so that if it fails nothing really happens. I'm not sure if this is possible though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bizarrely to handle this you simply need to make sure the fault and success responses are sent to the same subsequent flow element, like this:

[image: Routing the fault and success responses]

Once you do this you will find that no exception emails are sent and you can handle the errors appropriately within the flow itself (such as with an "ErrorScreen" as shown here). You can test "{!$Flow.FaultMessage}" to see if it is empty to decide on whether to show the error screen.

**UPDATE**: Based on comments it seems this doesn't work at the moment. This is likely due to [this known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001wcKgQAI).

Comment: +1 That's useful to know. Should be in the docs.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried exactly this on a Platform Event triggered flow where I handle the fault. And it still sends the darn email that I don't want it to send.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(

Comment: I can confirm that this solution also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Turns out since we took this approach something broke. There is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001wcKgQAI) covering this problem.